# Chrome Driver Maven Error "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session."

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber, maven

I am trying to run a selenium-based java test application on Intellij using maven. The problem is that if I run the test in IntelliJ the chrome driver starts and run successfully whereas if I Exeecute Maven Goal "mvn clean install" it gives the following result:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Following is my System Info:

> System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KU0P1BD', ip: '192.xxx.xx.x', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_301'

I have tried the following solutions after looking for the answers for the past two days:

1. Changed my selenium-java artifact under Pom.xml from ranges

- 4.1.0
- 4.0.0
- 4.0.0-rc-3
- 4.0.0-rc-2

2. Changed my JDK from:

- jdk1.8.0_301
- jdk1.8.0_311
- jdk-11.0.13

3. Tested it with the Chrome driver:

- 95.0.4638.69
- 96.0.4664.45

I have tried variations from the above with no luck at all.

My current Chrome version is:

> Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)

My current Chrome Driver version is:

> 96.0.4664.45

My current Java version is:

> java version "1.8.0_311"

My Current Maven version is:

> Maven home: C:\Software\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.4

> Java version: 1.8.0_311, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\jre

> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252

> OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

In IntelliJ my current Project SDK is:

> java version "1.8.0_311"

JAVA_HOME is set as:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311

Java path is set as:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin

MAVEN_HOME is set as:

> C:\Software\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.4

Maven path is set as:

> C:\Software\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin

My hosts file at C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts contains the following:

#localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

> 127.0.0.1       localhost

> ::1             localhost

I also tried to run my ChromeDriver instance with the help of WebDriverManager but it still had the same result when executed with maven.

The Firefox driver is running successfully both in Maven and IntelliJ itself. If there be a need for any more detail just let me know. I am here, for this error to be resolved.

Error Stack Trace:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: demoTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.363 sec <<< FAILURE!
Confirm the title of the Sign-up page(Blog Signup)  Time elapsed: 5.286 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:577)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:80)
    at stepdefs.demo_steps.iLaunchTheBrowser(demo_steps.java:22)
    at ✽.I launch the browser(file:///C:/Users/Azeem/IdeaProjects/chromeMavenTest/src/test/resources/demo.feature:6)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.1.0', revision: '87802e897b'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-KU0P1BD', ip: '192.168.10.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_311'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:80)
    at stepdefs.demo_steps.iLaunchTheBrowser(demo_steps.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.doInvoke(Invoker.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:24)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:86)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:57)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:95)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.lambda$run$0(PickleRunners.java:151)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$3(CucumberExecutionContext.java:110)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:110)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:144)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:196)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunBeforeAllHooks.evaluate(Cucumber.java:266)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunAfterAllHooks.evaluate(Cucumber.java:281)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$StartTestRun.evaluate(Cucumber.java:233)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$FinishTestRun.evaluate(Cucumber.java:248)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```